# Javascript object and getAttribute show different value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes, attr

Im attempting to get the value of the data-dropped attribute here. I want it to be true upon me clicking the hello text. Im logging the object and calling getAttribute() to check the value of data-dropped when the text is clicked.
The object shows the attribute as true,
whilst the getAttribute function shows it as false
Just wondered why this is?

HTML:

```
<h1 class='test' data-dropped="false">Hello</h1>

<script src="untitled.js"></script>
<script src="setdroppedval.js"></script>
```

untitled.js:

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dropped]');

el.forEach(function (item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        console.dir(this);
        console.log(this.getAttribute('data-dropped'));
    });
});
```

setdroppedval.js:

```
let ele = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dropped]');

ele.forEach(function (item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
         this.setAttribute('data-dropped', 'true');
    });
});
```

Ive already tried changing the order of the scripts and setting the attribute in one JS file instead of separating it. Both of these solutions work.
However, i want to retain my layout of code and get the value that is actually correct in the object.
Any advice or info on why this occurs and if theres a solution would be great

Comment: You have a timing issue. You are reading and setting the attribute at the same time using two different event handlers. Which one will be first? This depends on the browser implementation. If you *really* want to retain your code structure, you will have to wrap your `getAttribute()` call in `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)` to make sure it runs after setting it.

Comment: As to why `console.dir(this)` and `console.log(this.getAttribute())` show different values - keep in mind the second goes through the DOM, which usually does not update instantly after you set it. Then again, this depends on browser implementation, so you might get different results when testing it in different browsers.